# GD: Drag and drop in a PHP form

Tags: php, forms, gd

I am currently working with a GD image where I'm allowing the user to customize quite a few things via $_GET.
I'd like to know if it were to be possible to somehow (in a form) let a user 'drag and drop' 
a marker to the desired location where the text would be displayed on a 510x100 image to then send it to the page which generates the image.

Any ideas?

```
imagefttext($image, $fsize, 0, $mottox, $mottoy, $font_color, './volt.ttf', $motto);
--------------------------------
if(empty($_REQUEST['mottox'])){
    $mottox = '10';
}else{ 
        $mottox =$_REQUEST['mottox'];
}

if(empty($_REQUEST['mottoy'])){
    $mottoy = '60';
}else{ 
        $mottoy =$_REQUEST['mottoy'];
}
```

Comment: not server-side, but there may be client-side options.

Comment: What client-side options could be used?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this draggable solution http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

All you need is to get final position of text-container and send it to webserver.

Comment: Do you have any advices on how to get the final position of the text-container if it's contained inside a wrapper that is 510x100 px?